# Newton Raphson method equation solver algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, numerical-methods, newtons-method

In the code below, when I choose for example "max_n_iterations" to be equal to 1, the list "approximations", when printed, displays two elements where it should only display one (the initial x).

What is the reason for this?

```
#This exercise shows an immediate way to find the root of a real valued funciton, using   successive better approximations
#This method is known as Newton Raphson method

print 'Find the root of a given function - NEWTON RAPHSONS METHOD'
print 'The function is the following: ...'
x=input('Choose an initial estimate:') #An initial estimate is necessary to be choosen   to start the iteration process
x=float(x) #The number inserted is transformed into a floating point number
max_n_iterations=input('Choose max n. iterations:') #The user decides the maximum number   of iterations to run
approximations = [] #Vector collecting all the intermediate solutions; i.e. the  approximated roots evaluated before reaching the final solution 
iterations= []

def f(x):  #The given function has to be inserted manually in the code
return 2*x**3+45*x+1/x**2+16

def D(f):  #Evaluates the first derivative of the given function, using the definition of derivative 
def df(x, h): #x is the initial estimate, h is the increment
    return (f(x+h) - f(x))/h #Difference quotient
return df #First derivative

def newtons_method(f, x, h=0.000001, epsilon=0.000001,): #This is the main process: f is  the given function, x and h are the same as above, epsilon is the tolerance level. Epsilon  and h have to be choosen sufficiently small
df = D(f) #df is just the first derivative, as before
for i in range(max_n_iterations): #The code runs until the maximum number of iterations  is reached
    x1 = x - f(x)/df(x, h) #Essence of Newton Raphson method: the iteration process
    approximations.append(x) #Every intermediate solution is collected into a vector, as  defined above
    iterations.append(1)
    if abs(x1 - x) < epsilon: #When the absolute difference between two successive roots  is less than the tolerance level (i.e. the sequence of solutions strongly converges), the  program exists the cycle
        break
    x = x1 #The next solution becomes the starting solution in the new cycle
return x #Final solution

def final_solution(): #The final solution from the Newton Raphson method
return newtons_method(f,x) 

df=D(f) #These values have to be inserted again to allow the execution of the final step
h=0.000001
epsilon=0.000001
x=newtons_method(f,x)

if abs((x-f(x)/df(x,h))-x) < epsilon: #If (strong) convergence has been reached
   print 'Solution is:', final_solution() #Prints the final solution
   print 'Approximations before reaching convergence:', approximations #Prints the vector of intermediate solutions
   print 'Convergence has been reached after', len(iterations), 'iterations'
   print 'Newton Raphson method was successful!'
elif abs((x-f(x)/df(x,h))-x) >= epsilon: #If (strong) convergence has not been reached
   print 'Approximated solution is:', final_solution()
   print 'Approximations evaluated:', approximations
   print 'Convergence has not been reached after', max_n_iterations, 'iterations'
   print 'Newton Raphson method was not successful'
```

Comment: A good place to start would be Carmack's fast inverse square root, which does 2 (hard wired) iterations over an initial estimation for a function. Its as short a NR implementation can get, and should give you the general idea to expand into a more precise solution. Link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root

Comment: Thanks but my intention was to use the Newton Raphson method. I know it's possible to use this method but I'm just stuck on that loop

Comment: Ah you posted some code, let me read it and then I can give a more proper response!

Comment: I'm just leaving my workplace and couldn't get a clear read of this, I'm getting an itchy feeling from the rounding (why dot it?!?!). I'll check this later at home, but I think someone else might help you in between.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like before `newtons_method()` can return a value, it has to call itself again. For example:

```
def newtons_method(f, x, h=0.000001, epsilon=0.000001,):
    ...
    if abs((x - f(x)/df(x, h))-x)< epsilon:
       print 'Solution is:', round(newtons_method(f,x),6) # function called again here
       ...
       return x

    else:
       print 'Approximated solution is:', round(newtons_method(f,x),4) # and again here
       ...
       return x
```

So the first call to `newtons_method()` never returns because it has to call itself before `return`, and then that function call has to call itself before `return`, and then...

Can you modify your code so that `newtons_method()` isn't called recursively in this way?

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the error I was not discovering. I have modified "newtons_method" so that the function just prints x. I have also removed all the unnecessary roundings, as bconstanzo noticed.

Comment: The problem I still get is that it only executes the "else" condition, it never executes the "if" one...

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem, but it doesn't appear that you're comparing two successive roots in your `if` condition: `(x - f(x)/df(x, h)) - x`. Should that final `x` be your current guess at a root instead (and other instances of `x` in that expression your previous guess)?

Comment: final x is the final solution(root), while the first expression in bracket is just to check the convergence condition, to assess if the method was successful or not. Anyway, I wrote a better code which is probably more clear, I'm going to post it above.

Comment: With this NEW CODE I was able to have it almost done, the only trouble remaining is that I do not understand why if I choose "max_n_iterations" to be equal 1 for instance, the resulting list named "approximations" displays more than 1 element when printed

Answer (score 0):

As ajcr said, don't call newton's method to obtain the solution from within newton's method.  f(x) is all you need.

Secondly, your while loop needs to terminate when abs(x-x1) < epsilon (sign error).  Note that as you've coded it right now.  I'd also guarantee that you enter the while loop at least once so that the approximated solutions array gets populated.

Comment: Isn't it the way I wrote it? While abs(x1-x)>epsilon, the loop keeps executing, when this absolute difference becomes lower, it exits  the loop. Could you please tell me what do you mean by entering the while loop at least once? Thanks a lot!